# Applying .rolling to a pandas dataframe with objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes with one column each. One has floating values as entries:

```
a=pandas.DataFrame([[2],[5],[7]])
```

whist the other one consists of tuples of values, such as:

```
b=pandas.DataFrame([[(1,2)],[(4,5)],[(6,7)]])
```

I want to use a rolling apply to perform an operation on these elements. To keep everything extremely simple, imagine that I want to perform the identity operation. So in this case I just copy the elements (the real code will calculate differences between coordinates (the tuples)).

`a.rolling(1).apply(lambda x:x)` works for the single values.
But performing `b.rolling(1).apply(lambda x:x)` on the tuples
gives the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object
```

It seems to be very weird that any of these methods are actually dependent on the type of objects stored inside the dataframe.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
I need to pass 2 consecutive tuples as an argument to another function (to calculate distances). So I really need access to tuples, and not just to their values.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will help -

```
b[0].apply(pd.Series).rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[1]-x[0]).apply(tuple, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
0    (nan, nan)
1    (3.0, 3.0)
2    (2.0, 2.0)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't think this will help in my specific case.

I want to use geopy, to calculate distance between coordinates (a tuple of lattitude and longitude). This takes as argument two tuples (one for each point) and returns a distance. So I really need to pass the tuples themselves, and not just their elements.